# Angular 2 not working in IE11

Tags: angular, typescript, polyfills

I am getting the following error in IE 11

```
Script5022: Error: No provider for t!
```

I am using angular 2 CLI and have seen a lot of talk about updating the Shims which I have done but to no avail.

**polyfil.ts**

```
// This file includes polyfills needed by Angular 2 and is loaded before
// the app. You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es7/observable';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "hammerjs"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing this issue? It works perfectly fine in Chrome, Safari and Friefox.

Comment: you have to find what part of code causing this error first. Try it with empty component?